# Surface from metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a metric $g_{i,j}$, in two dimensions for example. How do I find the surface that it represents, in paramatrized form, as a function $z=f(x,y)$, etc. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to obtain a unique function if given only the metric. I will work the problem backwards to illustrate why. I am assuming this a perfectly orientable surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  $${(ds)^2}={(dx)^2}+{(dy)^2}+{(dz)^2}$$
Write out the constraint $${dz}={(∂f/∂x)}{dx}+{(∂f/∂y)}{dy}$$
Plug it into the metric and you get $${(ds)^2}={(1+(∂f/∂x)^2)}{(dx)^2}+{(1+(∂f/∂y)^2)}{(dy)^2}+{2(∂f/∂x)(∂f/∂y)}{dx}{dy}$$
You now have:
$${g_{12}}={(∂f/∂x)(∂f/∂y)}=g_{21}$$
$${g_{11}}={(1+(∂f/∂x)^2)}$$
$${g_{22}}={(1+(∂f/∂y)^2)}$$

Given an arbitrary functions as metric components, there may not be any solution possible. For example, if ${g_{11}}=cos(x^2+y^2)/2$ it be impossible to find a surface in this case. Supposing we do find a solution, $f(x,y)$, against all odds, it is not unique. For example $z=f(x,y)+c$ where $c$ is a constant is also a valid surface in such a case.

Comment: (+1) @dj_mummy this example looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

In general: you don't.  There are metrics without a corresponding surface.

Michael